# Jetpack compose - sticky header with alpha color items overlap header

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've similar problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72604009/jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-items-scroll-over-stickyheader-and-does-not-scroll-to) where my items in LazyColumn overlap the sticky header.
The problem is that my header background has Alpha (the color is `white.copy(alpha = 0.15f`))

When I change the background color to Black, it works fine, but I need this specific color.

I also tried to use a Card with elevation, but it doesn't help

```
Card(
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                        containerColor = white_alpha15
                    ),
                    shape = RectangleShape,
                    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 5.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillParentMaxWidth()
                        .clickable(onClick = {
                            onClick(header)
                        }, enabled = true),
                    ) {
                    Row(
                        Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    ) { 
                              .../...
                       }
                    }
```

Is it possible to have a sticky header with a alpha color and not have this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `compositeOver(Color)` when defining the background color for the header. This will create a new color with the desired alpha value applied without making it transparent:

```kotlin
val white_alpha15 = white.copy(alpha = 0.15f).compositeOver(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
```

Then the header background will be opaque when displayed over the list contents.